# Will a serial port connection close outside of the SerialPort.Close() method?

Tags: c#, serial-port

This is more a question in theory rather than in practice as I'm currently unable to test it due to the lack of a rather bulky device I use to test the program I am creating. My question is, will a serial port, in its life time, close without `SerialPort.Close()` being called? Moreover is there any risk that the connection will time out before the method is called?

Also, is there any reason I should close it when done issuing a command and reopen it when I need to submit a new one or is it safe to keep open at all times?

Comment: Second part: not really, unless there are other services on the system vying for that port. Otherwise, the port will be released once your app closes/crashes. Furthermore, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.close.aspx suggests that you should avoid closing the port then expecting to re-open in immediately.

Comment: What if you unplug the cable?

Comment: In my experience, as long as the com port, say `Com1`, exists and access to it isn't locked by another program, C# doesn't particularly care if a device or even a cable is connected to the serial port. I've never seen it time out. Read timeouts happen but do nothing to affect the open/closed state of the serial port. I've just not had a chance to effectively test this for a lengthy amount of time.

Comment: FWIW, data acquisition service applications that we deploy keep serial ports open for months on end with no issues. The service does read from and/or write to them quite frequently, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serial *connections* (meaning the physical connection or port object) never timeout, even if you unplug the cable.  However, if the serial port is a USB converter, the device can be disabled if the USB side is unplugged which will break the serial connection.

SerialPort is IDisposable, so if you dispose it, it will close.

Serial Timeouts only occur if you do a Read and there is no data. This has no affect on the SerialPort device or connection. (Serial Timeouts can also occur on Writes, but this is much less common. This only happens if handshaking is involved and the receiver is blocking reception.)

Comment: Since there's absolutely no reason to dispose of the serial port connection I have established in the program before exiting it, is there any reason to close and reopen it when I'm not submitting commands?

Comment: Unless you are sharing the port with some other program, I don't see a reason.